# How to split content into two columns (need some space between the columns) using itextsharp

Tags: itext7

I am supposed to print a pdf using itextsharp. My requirement is to split the page into two columns (need some space between the columns). I dont have an idea how to do this. Can you help me on this. I am using the version 7(itext)

Comment: Are you using iTextSharp (version 5) or are you using iText 7 for .NET. Please edit your post to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

To have a multi-column rendering mode, you can use `ColumnDocumentRenderer` class:

```
Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
Rectangle[] columns = new Rectangle[] {
     new Rectangle(30, 30, 200, 750), // coordinates of first column
     new Rectangle(300, 30, 200, 750) // coordinates of second column
}));
document.SetRenderer(new ColumnDocumentRenderer(document, columns));
```

Then just add elements to the document as usual:

```
document.Add(new Paragraph("Text string"));
```

Comment: I have a list say there are 32 records in it .... I want to divide a A4 sheet into 8 i.e  2 rows and 8 columns .... And bind the record in 4 A4 Sheets...... I want to do this itextsharp . Can you guide me

Comment: Do the same thing I showed you, but add more areas to the array of columns